# React elements created through createRoot cannot call Provider values

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I created a function like below in React.
I usually render through array.map, but I tested it in a different way.

```
export async function layerCreate(id) {
    const layerArea = document.getElementById("layerArea");

    const layer = document.createElement("div");
    layer.classList.add("layer");

    await layerArea.append(layer);

    const root = await createRoot(layer);
    await root.render(<Layer id={id}/>);
}
```

This function attaches a new react element to an empty div called layerArea. layerArea is wrapped with a value called GlobalProvider using useContext.

```
<GlobalProvider>
    <div id="layerArea" className="layerArea"></div>;
</GlobalProvider>
```

When a Layer element was added under the layerArea using the above function, I tried to call the GlobalProvider value through useContext in the Layer element. But the value comes out as undefined.

I wonder why the value of Provider cannot be used in the react element created in the Provider child element through createRoot.

Comment: You  would typically expect only one "root" element, is there a reason you likely have more than one? [`createPortal`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) _may_ (as I haven't tested it recently) allow what you're after...  https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#:~:text=When%20you%20want%20to%20render%20a%20piece%20of%20JSX%20in%20a%20different%20part%20of%20the%20DOM%20tree%20that%20isn%E2%80%99t%20a%20child%20of%20your%20component%20(for%20example%2C%20a%20modal%20or%20a%20tooltip)%2C%20use%20createPortal%20instead%20of%20createRoot.

Comment: When I used `createPortal`, it worked fine. I just wondered why I couldn't use the Provider's variables when using `createRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason that using another "root element" (using `createRoot`) doesn't allow access to your Provider from the main application is because React sees the new "root element" as a *different* initialisation of React (they sometimes call this "Root Fiber Node").

It's effectively like having multiple React Apps running in the page (much like how you can initialise several React Widgets at once).

Once the "Root Node" is registered (and attached to the DOM), the React code renders the components with all the relevant React code (in your case that's everything in `Layer`, and everything that subsequently renders *"underneath"* that).

**Note:** *"underneath"* in terms of the Element Tree (aka [UI Tree](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#the-ui-tree))

The process is different between `React18` and older versions, with the abandonment of ["Concurrent Mode"](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html), but the developer experience and end result is largely the same

There are some caveats for `createRoot` (from the [Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/createRoot#createroot))

> Caveats
>
> - If your app is server-rendered, using `createRoot()` is not supported. Use [`hydrateRoot()`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot) instead.
> - You’ll likely have only one `createRoot` call in your app. If you use a framework, it, might do this call for you.
> - When you want to render a piece of JSX in a different part of the DOM tree that isn’t a child of your component (for example, a modal or a tooltip), use [`createPortal`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) instead of `createRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using React's `createRoot` method to create a root of your application, it's important to note that the elements created within it won't have access to context values provided higher up the component tree using Provider.

This is because `createRoot` is meant for concurrent mode, where React can start rendering asynchronously, and thus it doesn't allow synchronous rendering (like with `ReactDOM.render`). Context values provided by `Provider` won't be available during the initial render in concurrent mode, which is when `createRoot` is used.

To work with context values within elements created through `createRoot`, you can use the `useContext` hook to access the context directly within your component.

Here's an example:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom';

const MyContext = createContext();

const App = () => {
    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value="Hello from Context!">
           <RootComponent />
        </MyContext.Provider>
    );
};

const RootComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = () => {
  const contextValue = useContext(MyContext);

  return <p>{contextValue}</p>;
};

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);
```